# List index out of bounds: 0

Tags: apex

How can I solve the List index out of bounds: 0  issue .

```
  ID Accid;

  Account[] acc = [Select id,name from account where name ='test']; -->1
  if(acc.size() >0){
     Accid = acc[0].id;
   }else {
    Account[] acc1 =[Select id,name from Account where name = 'test 1'];-->2
    if(acc1.size()>0){
       Accid = acc1[0].id;
     }
   }

  User[] u = [Select id,Name from User Where Accountid=:Accid];-->3 
  if(u.size() >0){ //here throw the error like List index out of bounds: 0
    //some logic here
    //
   }

  ------some code---------
  --- some code-----------
  ---- some code----------
```

Here i got issue that is 1 query executed then 3 query executed size 0 after iI am not get any error executed next lines that's work fine. but 2 query executed then 3 query executed size 0 now next lines not  executed that's throw the error like List index out of bounds: 0

Comment: Are you sure the second Account query returns a value?

Comment: @Kittu : did your issue got sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the wrong array in the second `if` statement, see the `BAD LINE` comment in the code below

```
ID Accid;

Account[] acc = [Select id,name from account where name ='test']; -->1
if (acc.size() > 0) {
    Accid = acc[0].id;
} else {
    Account[] acc1 =[Select id,name from Account where name = 'test 1'];-->2
    if (acc1.size() > 0) {
        Accid = acc[0].id; // BAD LINE, should be Accid = acc1[0].id
    }
}

User[] u = [Select id,Name from User Where Accountid=:Accid];-->3
```

Comment: hi Ralph thanks for your response actually my post is wrong this is actual code. pls help...                                                               ID Accid;

Account[] acc = [Select id,name from account where name ='test']; -->1
if (acc.size() > 0) {
    Accid = acc[0].id;
} else {
    Account[] acc1 =[Select id,name from Account where name = 'test 1'];-->2
    if (acc1.size() > 0) {
        Accid = acc1[0].id; 
    }
}

User[] u = [Select id,Name from User Where Accountid=:Accid];-->3

Comment: might i suggest actually formatting a bit?  you're braces don't even match

Comment: also, edit your question, commenting code just doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you should do like below. In else condition you should do `acc1[0].id` but you are doing `acc[0].id` where acc is not has any vaue thats why you are getting this Out Of bound exception.

```
List<Account> acc = [Select id,name from account where name ='test'];
if(acc.size() >0){ 
Accid = acc[0].id; 
} else { 
List<Account> acc1 =[Select id,name from Account where name = 'test 1'];
 if(acc1.size()>0){ 
Accid = acc1[0].id; } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response pramod now you look at my question i edited some lines ..pls give any suggestions...